# UITableView dataSource must return a cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to display two different UITableViewCells I have made in InterfaceBuilder, however I am receiving this error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

I have create two new nib's I have changed the file owners class to the UITableViewController I am trying to display them in, and hooked them up using IBOutlets etc.

The error happens inside **TableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath** and this is what my method for that class looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 
    // Configure the cell...
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        // Manufactures --->
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = nil;
            if (cell == nil) {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CodeSearchTextCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = codeSearchTextCell; //Loads tableviewcells with custome xib-cell that I have made in Interface builder
                self.codeSearchTextCell = nil;
            }
            codeTextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
            codeTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
        else if  (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = nil;
            if (cell == nil) {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CodeSearchCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = codeSearchCell; //Loads tableviewcells with custome xib-cell that I have made in Interface builder
                self.codeSearchCell = nil;
            }
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; //adds disclosure indicator
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but can see clearly when putting the break point on the last line where I return the cell its coming back with no value.

Comment: My guess is the index path is not for section 0 or that the row is greater than one. Also, why do you dequeue a cell then throw it away? This is going to make for choppy scrolling if you create a new cell every time.

Comment: It is for section 0. I only have 1 section and 2 rows. I have debugged and the thread dose make it into that if statement. I am throwing it away straight away because there will be no new cells to display. bit overkill maybe but thats just what I decided easy fix really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, I assume you have a `UIView` subclass named `CodeSearchCell`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (0 == indexPath.section) {

        if (0 == indexPath.row) {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CodeSearchTextCell" owner:self options:nil];
            CodeSearchTextCell *codeSearchTextCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CodeSearchCell"];

            if ( nil == codeSearchTextCell ) {
                codeSearchTextCell = (CodeSearchTextCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            cell = codeSearchTextCell;

        } else if (1 == indexPath.row) {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CodeSearchCell" owner:self options:nil];
            CodeSearchCell *codeSearchCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CodeSearchCell"];

            if ( nil == codeSearchCell ) {
                codeSearchCell = (CodeSearchCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            cell = codeSearchCell;

        } else {

           // If indexPath.row > 1
           // Add logic to make sure cell isn't nil.

    } else {

        // If indexPath.section > 0
        // Add logic to make sure cell isn't nil.

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How do I account for the different CodeSearchTextCell nib for the first cell?

Comment: @HurkNburkS You use the same `indexPath.row` checks that you're currently using.

Comment: I updated the answer to handle all the situations. I didn't see that you were handling two types of cells the first time I read your question. I did this from memory, so their maybe a typo or two.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try it this way hope it will help you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        // Manufactures --->
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = nil;
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CodeSearchTextCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            codeTextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
            codeTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
        else if  (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = nil;
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CodeSearchCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; //adds disclosure indicator
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```